# Xcode7 iPhone実機通信エラー NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode7

iPhone実機でlocalhostのRailsサーバに接続しようとするとエラーが発生します。
iOS9から追加されたATSの機能はAllow Arbitary LoadsをYESに設定しているので切っています。
iPhoneシミュレータでは問題なく接続できています。
しかし、iOS9.1の実機のみならずiOS8.2の実機でもサーバに接続しよとするとエラーが発生してしまいます。

環境
Xcode7.1
iPhone実機iPhone6(iOS9.1)、iPhone5s(iOS8.2)
エラーコード
NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004

どなたか本エラーの解決方法ご存知でしたら教えて下さい。

Comment: -1004はCannotConnectToHostなのでATSの設定が間違えてたり、古いファイルが残ってたりしませんか？後、もし可能なら接続使用しているURLを教えてください。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

実機からもlocalhostというhost名でアクセスしてませんか？  
同じネットワーク内からサーバを立てているPCのipアドレスを指定したらいけると思います。  
ターミナルから `ifconfig | grep 192` でそれっぽいのは取れると思います。

Comment: 実機からもlocalhostからアクセスしていました。PCのipアドレスを利用したら接続できました。ありがとうございます。